# how to display node hit in drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

i want to add page hit to nodes on my drupal site.how can i do that?

Answer (score 6):

Use the built-in Statistics module to add a pure page count.  If you want to display the number of unique visitors that visit a page, you will need to use the [Statistics Advanced module](http://drupal.org/project/statistics_advanced) .This module counts the number of unique IP addresses per visit, while the Drupal core Statistics module increments its count every time the node is viewed.

Answer (score 2):

What might work easier is "Node view count" module: http://drupal.org/project/nodeviewcount

I also came accross this other useful "Visitors" module: http://drupal.org/project/visitors

Hope this helps...options are always good :)

Answer (score 0):

The built-in Statistics module offers this.

Answer (score 0):

After enabling the Statistics module, you can en/disable and configure it here: Administer -> Reports -> Access log settings (admin/reports/settings). The Statistics Advanced module's configuration is there, also.